# Getting the Youtube's search page URL using the Youtube API

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using the YouTube API in PHP.

For a specified query, I want:

- The URL for the search page
- The URL for the search page in a channel

For example:

- If the query is 'Luke Cage', I want the URL:

  `https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=luke+cage`
- If I wanted to search only the Netflix channel, I want the URL:

  `https://www.youtube.com/user/NewOnNetflix/search?query=luke+cage`

The only way I know how to do this is to figure the url out by inspection. However, I want to use the API because the URL structure may change for example and less likely to hit bugs.